# Practices to maintain historical data via replication?

Tags: oracle, mongodb, goldengate

We have a use case like of banks, where we generate large number of transactions, say in `transaction` table and few other tables with large number of inserts, every day. Transactions are most inserted and updated within a day or two. Our database is Oracle 12c(planned upgrade to 19). Coming to use case, we need to set up a big data cluster(Oracle or mongo/cassandra) ,say , X so we can support people fetching account statement of older time.

So, in our primary(and data guard replicated standby) Oracle database, we should keep 3 months of data and people querying for data older than 3 months must use cluster X.

What are the industry practices for building such replications?

Process must be:

- Stable,resilient and well monitored
- Cluster X must be scalable
- Highly consistent and must not ever loose data

What are our initial thoughts:

Set up oracle goldengate pipeline from source DB to a y-nodes sharded oracle DB cluster. Although Oracle19c sharded db does supports adding a node with auto balancing, I'm reluctant to use a relational db. Not using relational DB and using replication to DBs like Mongo/cassandra also making me skeptical of instabilities in CDC pipelines, NoSQL inconsistency.

What does banks do for such cases?

Comment: "*What does banks do for such cases?*" - They don't typically split up the data by age between clusters (of the queryable data to the end users). 3 months of data will unlikely be enough to split up.

Comment: @J.D., 3 months is just an example. I have seen banks offer different ways to generate account statements, for last 1 years vs more older data. Last 1 year's reports are generated instantly and older data reports are generated in few hours. I assume they keep older data in a separate cluster else the main DB's table size would grow to unmanageable size.

Comment: "*I have seen banks offer different ways to generate account statements, for last 1 years vs more older data.*" - That's why I said "*of the queryable data to the end users*". The actual statements will only go back so far but all of that data is within the same table and cluster *usually*. After that cutoff of 1 year or a few years is when the end users won't have access to that data anymore. If data from it is available, it's usually offered as a summarized dataset, probably living in a separate summary table, and quite possibly on the same cluster still.